# AJAX forms first-child not submitting when every other form does

Tags: javascript, php, forms, jquery

I have a series of dynamically created forms that allow a user to update various sections on a webpage. When submitted the form is supposed to update the database and echo a success alert. No matter how many list elements there are the first form of the list seems not to work (no idea why) any ideas?

**NOTE** when submitting the form in the first LI (the one that never works) it returns a success statement (that the AJAX works) but does not update the database. I have played around making sure the IDs line up to the SQL db being queried and it matches up fine, but the form in the first child refuses to update

**Page**

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'ajax') or die ('error could not connect');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM data";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('error could not query');

    echo '<ul>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<li>';
            echo '<form class="form">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">';
                echo '<input type="text" name="data" value="'.$row['data'].'">';
                echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">';
            echo '</form>';        
        echo '</li>';   
    }
    echo '</ul>';

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<script>
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    $.ajax({ // Starter Ajax Call
       type: "POST",        
       url: 'update.php', 
       data: $('form').serialize(),
       success: function() {
        alert('updated');    
       }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
</script>
```

**Update.php**

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $data = $_POST['data'];

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'ajax') or die ('error could not connect');
    $query = "UPDATE data SET data = '$data' WHERE id = $id";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('error could not query');
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**HTML OUTPUT**

```
<ul>
 <li>
    <form>
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3">
     <input type="text" name="data" value="change">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form></li> //Does not update SQL specific row
 <li><form></form></li> //updates fine
 <li><form></form></li> //updates fine
 <li><form></form></li> //updates fine
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you want the data in all form to be submitted when you submit any form?

Comment: ideally just the form thats being updated but all the forms are created dynmaically and the number of them will vary all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have `$('form').serialize()` which will attempt serialize the data of all forms. What you should do is serialize the form that is being submitted `$(this).serialize()`.

```
<script>
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    $.ajax({ // Starter Ajax Call
       type: "POST",        
       url: 'update.php', 
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function() {
        alert('updated');    
       }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
</script>
```